# Android numberpicker, never pass from OnValueChangedListener breakpoint

Tags: android, listener, numberpicker

I extended the NumberPicker class, I overrided to the setOnValueChangedListener but when I debug the code and I click on the plus button of the numberpicker, it never pass in my breakpoint inside the method setOnValueChangedListener.
Something is wrong?

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)//For backward-compability
public class NumberPickerCustom extends NumberPicker 
{
    private int clickNumber = 0;

    public NumberPickerCustom(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NumberPickerCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        processAttributeSet(attrs);
    }

    public NumberPickerCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        processAttributeSet(attrs);
    }
    private void processAttributeSet(AttributeSet attrs) {
        //This method reads the parameters given in the xml file and sets the properties according to it
        this.setMinValue(attrs.getAttributeIntValue(null, "min", 0));
        this.setMaxValue(attrs.getAttributeIntValue(null, "max", 0));
        this.setValue(attrs.getAttributeIntValue(null, "value", 0));
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnValueChangedListener(
            OnValueChangeListener onValueChangedListener) 
    {
        super.setOnValueChangedListener(onValueChangedListener);
        if (onValueChangedListener==null)
        {
            onValueChangedListener = new OnValueChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) 
                {
                    clickNumber++;
                    if (clickNumber>10)
                    {
                        clickNumber = -1000;
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Clicca sul numero centrale per inserire direttamente un valore", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need a custom number picker to set min max value . you can use `np.setMaxValue(100); np.setMinValue(0)`. Why do you need a custom number picker?

Comment: Yes I know, I only think that it's more elegant :D
But the problem is not this, do u know why the listener is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initializze your custom number picker

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_random_block, container, false);
 NumberPickerCustom np = (NumberPickerCustom) rootView.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerCustom);
 np.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
```

Make sure your class implements

```
  implements OnValueChangeListener
```

Then

```
@Override
public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicca sul numero centrale per inserire direttamente un valore", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
}
```

Snap shot:

When you the value changes you get to see the toast modify the same according to your requirement.

[image]

Edit :

Change your custom NumberPicker as below

```
public class NumberPickerCustom extends NumberPicker implements OnValueChangeListener
{
    public NumberPickerCustom(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NumberPickerCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        processAttributeSet(attrs);
    }

    public NumberPickerCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        processAttributeSet(attrs);
    }
    private void processAttributeSet(AttributeSet attrs) {
        //This method reads the parameters given in the xml file and sets the properties according to it
        this.setMinValue(attrs.getAttributeIntValue(null, "min", 0));
        this.setMaxValue(attrs.getAttributeIntValue(null, "max", 0));
        this.setValue(attrs.getAttributeIntValue(null, "value", 0));
        this.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "New Value is"+newVal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }  
}
```

Snap shot

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rag! I already know this way to fix it. I was just wondering why I can't set the listener from the custom class. Maybe I'm wrong, but I think it's appropriate set it from the custom class.
I'm just here to learn something :D Thanks anyway! ;)

Comment: @Accollativo you have to initialize your custom number picker and then set the listener for the same. Just like button. you initialize and then set the listener.

Comment: @Accollativo read reto meier Professional Android Development book. There is topic on custom views and handling events. I think its very useful. Do check the book.

Comment: @Accollativo you are weclcome glad to help. Do check that book it will help